# add instance of class to listbox from .txt visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, listbox

New at visual basic. I'm trying to read from a csv file, split it, then take values only at index(0) and add them all to a listbox. Here's what I got. Any advice I'd appreciate.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim data() As String
        Dim initFileContents() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("MembershipPhone.txt")
        data = initFileContents.First.Split(","c)
        name = data(0)
        phone = data(1)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(name)
        TextBox1.Text = name
        TextBox2.Text = phone
End Sub
```

Of course this only adds the first instance. I need C++ equivalent to "for each line in data.."

Comment: What is your problem exactly.?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a For loop to iterate over the lines returned by ReadAllLines():

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim data() As String
    For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("MembershipPhone.txt")
        data = line.Split(","c)
        Name = data(0)
        phone = data(1)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Name)
        TextBox1.Text = Name
        TextBox2.Text = phone
    Next
End Sub
```